# implementation of AVL tree toString()

Tags: java, stringbuilder, avl-tree

This is my toString() but it doesn't work properly

```
public String toString() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("{");
        traverse(root, str);
        str.append("}");

        return str.toString();
    }

    private void traverse(TreeNode node, StringBuilder str){
        if (node == null){
            return;
        }

        if (node.left != null) {
            traverse(node.left, str);
            str.append(", ");
        }

        str.append(node.left);

        if (node.right != null) {
            str.append(", ");
            traverse(node.right, str);
        }
    }
```

this is what the method print out:
{null, AbstractTreeMap$TreeNode@15a8767}

any help is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (node.left != null) {
      inOrder(node.left, result);
      result.append(", ");
}

result.append(node.left); //should not be node.left
```

do this instead

```
if (node.left != null) {
     inOrder(node.left, result);
     result.append(", ");
}

result.append(node); //this will print the node itself
```

Also `TreeNode` does not have `toString()` method overridden so it shows the hash code.

Comment: Not a correct implementation. A) A tree consisting of a single node produces an empty string B) The root is never printed C) Unnecessary commas are added.

Comment: @EyalSchneider the null in the toString() was due to this line, so just pointed out the mistake. True the logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

1. The recursive method should call result.append(node) rather than result.append(node.left)
2. Your TreeNode class should override toString (displaying some node id), otherwise you'll see the default toString (from Object), which looks like "AbstractTreeMap$TreeNode@15a8767"